# Nestjs encrypt password pre-save @nestjs/mongoose

Tags: typescript, nestjs

Trying to encrypt password before save with @nestjs/mongoose. Read some examples and they're written like the following pseudocode:

```
UsersSchema.pre('save', (next: any) => {
  if (!this.isModified('password')) return next();
  this.password = encrypt(this.password, 10);
  next();
});
```

there's no type to this so i console.log to get the info and it seems like it's a completely different object.

```
// user.entity.ts
const UsersSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Users);

UsersSchema.pre('save', () => {
  console.log(this);
});

export { UsersSchema };
```

log result:

```
 {
   Users: [class Users],
   UsersSchema: Schema {
     obj: {
       username: [Object],
       name: [Object],
       email: [Object],
       password: [Object]
     },
     paths: {
       username: [SchemaString],
       name: [SchemaString],
       email: [SchemaString],
       password: [SchemaString],
       _id: [ObjectId],
       __v: [SchemaNumber]
     },
     aliases: {},
     subpaths: {},
     ...and more
```

no clue how this works and i couldn't find this at the docs. Maybe i'm doing it the wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The @nestjs/mongoose hook function pre, post(['save', 'findOneAndUpdate']) is usually used in the useFactory function.

However, to access your docs, pass docs and next as shown below

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeatureAsync([
      {
        name: Cat.name,
        imports: [ConfigModule],
        useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => {
          const schema = AccountSchema;
          schema.pre('save', function(docs, next: NextFunction) {
            if(docs!.isActive){
              //send New Email
            }
          });
          return schema;
        },
        inject: [ConfigService],
      },
    ]),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

```
UsersSchema.pre('save', function (docs, next: NextFunction)  {
```

Answer (score 0):

try using regular function instead of arrow function, that should fix it!

```
UsersSchema.pre('save', function (next: any)  {
  if (!this.isModified('password')) return next();
  this.password = encrypt(this.password, 10);
  next();
});
```